# get correct return type of validate method of class-transformer

Tags: typescript, nestjs, class-validator

```
import { Exclude, plainToInstance } from 'class-transformer';
```

an entity that the controller should return

```
class SomeEntity {
  email: string;
  @Exclude()
  password: string;
}
```

an object returned from db

```
const user: SomeEntity = {
  email: 'dasd',
  password: 'das',
};
```

an object with already excluded fields

```
const userWithExcludedFields = plainToInstance(SomeEntity, user);
```

result of it

```
//the password field isn't included in userWithoutExcludedFields but still I haven't any error about it.
userWithExcludedFields.password;
```